# Вопрос с мобильной версией

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня на сайте есть слайдер, написал его сам. Чтобы затемнить картинку, наложил псевдоэлемент ::before на картинку. При просмотре с мобильного, этот затемнённый фон не отображается. Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Учитывая, что это ваш собственный код, при его отсутствии в вопросе, вряд ли кто-то вам поможет.

Comment: может есть общее решение для таких вопросов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы затемнить картинку, можно использовать `filter: brightness(n%)`. Это будет рациональней и, вероятно, утянет проблемы с отображением на разных устройствах, хотя бы потому что дополнительных элементов не создается. Пример:

```
css:

.image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url('https://images.app.goo.gl/bicMRQgxerhyfAUH9');
  filter: brightness(75%);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните ваш ответ примером, как сделать то что вы рекомендуете. После достижения определенного порога репутации, вы сможете оставлять комментарии. Ответы же следует оформлять так, чтобы у задавшего вопрос не возникало дополнительных вопросов.

Comment: Отличное решение :) спасибо.